# How can i automate VT 500 terminal mainframe application using UFT

Tags: hp-uft, mainframe, terminal-emulator

I have to automate a mainframe application which is present on **VT500 terminal** using UFT. I just want to know

1. Is it possible?
2. what all is required with UFT( Any plugin/Addons).
3. Also please share the steps.

Answer (score 0):

UFT has a **Terminal Emulator** add-on but I'm not sure if it supports `VT500`, in the [PAM (Product Availability Matrix)](https://admhelp.microfocus.com/uft/en/PAM/UFT_14.xx_PAM.pdf) it says that `VT100` is supported but no mention of `VT500`. You can read more about it [here](https://admhelp.microfocus.com/uft/en/14.50/UFT_Help/Content/Addins_Guide/TE_Addin_Overview.htm).

[image: PAM screenshot]

Comment: Yes, UFT support VT100. There is no information about VT500 in google :( . Thanks for the information.

Comment: The higher-numbered VT models are supersets of VT100 (usually color or other features), so a VT500 would support the basic VT100 set.

Answer (score 0):

Rational Functional Tester supports 3270 terminal interfaces. VT100 is considered a "dumb terminal", as it has one plane of data. 3270 is a richer terminal, and for proper testing, you should connect via 3270, rather than VT100.